# What kind of flowers are these seeds from?

Tags: identification, flowers, seeds

These are some seeds that someone gave me. I think they're some sort of flower, but I'm not sure.[image]

Comment: Nice question & illustration; also, the size or something in the illustration to show scale would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Hollyhocks! (*Alcea rosea*) A very tall flower much found in traditional gardens and loved by children for constructing dolls with dresses.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely holly hocks they look like my seed they sre the mallow family, some people like using them for a medicinal plant and for making teas